# Calling a different action from view using jQuery Ajax fnc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

My view url is /Customer/Detail/1

I would like to update a `div` element in this view, but I cannot reach the action method. I am using jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "List",
            data: formData,
            success: function(newHtml) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                     $("#grid").html(newHtml);
                }, 500);
            },

            error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("AJAX error: " + request.statusText);
            }
        });
```

The issue is with the `url` value. Eveything from this url attribute is added to the end of the actual view url. So for this example I'll get `/Customer/Detail/List` but I need `/Customer/List` or even `/Order/List`

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try typing the url with a starting slash. Like that:

`url: "/Customer/List"`

Answer (score 0):

do method in /Customer/Detail/List and then redirect it to /Customer/List or /Order/List

Comment: Why I cannot call it direct ?